# how to read csv file and apply it to tensor flow

Tags: csv, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensor flow i was trying to learn how to read data in a csv containin two features and one label and got stuck with the following error

[I here by attach the csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8qvPLsyp8dVkN4Tl8xUmtBVU0/view?usp=sharing)

```
df=pd.read_csv("intro_to_ann.csv")

X=tf.placeholder("float",[None,2])
y_=tf.placeholder("float",2)


W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,2]))
print(W)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
print(b)
y= tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)#predicted value


error = tf.square(y - y_)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(error)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

errors = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
 X_data, Y_data = np.array(df.ix[:,0:2]), np.array(df.ix[:,2])
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    for (x_d,y_d) in zip(X_data,Y_data):
        print(x_d)
        print(y_d)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x_d,y_:y_d})
```

I got this error

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_33:0', which has shape '(2, 2)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefined y in your code. Pick different names for placeholder and data variable. It should work OK.

Comment: thanks for helping me in that, i changed the source code as above and got the shape error. can you take a look at it and help me where i am going wrong in defining the size of inputs and output.
        `

Comment: You again used same name for different nodes: y = tf.placeholder("float",2) and y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W) + b) #predicted value. That's not a right way. Choose different names for them.

Comment: can you direct me where i am using the same name and where do i need to change exactly in the code!

Comment: i got it i changed them, even then my error was same i was missing something in defining the shape of my place holdr's my input X has two features and i choose[None,2] since the vector size is 2 and my feeding data has two feautures can any one help me how to define these sizes

Comment: ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_83:0', which has shape '(?, 2)' is the error that i got, can any one help me regarding this please.

Comment: How can i feed 500 or many inputs of this format  [1 2] as features and the corresponding output to y which i tried in the above code.